# Test lots of variable once, and only the true ones get affected

Tags: javascript

So, i've been trying in a while but i couldn't do it.

I got 8 variables tested in once if a custom attribute is "nao":

```
if (CNome=="nao"||CMail=="nao"||CCor=="nao"||CBan=="nao"||CMen=="nao"||Ctem=="nao"||CCont=="nao"||Cnota=="nao"){
               alert("Alguns campos estão incorretos, por favor complete-os.")
            return false   
         }
```

and i need to make every variables with "nao" indicated, so i can make a certain label class changed, any ideas in how can i select every variable with "nao"? i can make 8 Ifs, but it would take too much space D:

Answer (score 1):

```
var fields = [CNome, CMail, CCor, CBan, CMen, Ctem, CCont, Cnota];
var naos = [];

for(var i = 0; i<fields.length; i++) {
  if(fields[i] === "nao") {
    // either add them to an array for later processing:
    naos.push(fields[i]);

    // or do something with them:
    doSomething(fields[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you were thinking `var fields = {CNome : '', etc}`? With the array, `fields[i]` will never be "não", it will always be the field named.

Comment: OP: `make every variables with "nao" indicated`. He wants the variables that contain "nao", not the String "nao".

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, I read your code as an array of variable names, not values.